# Strange styling through injected stylesheets in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, primefaces

We've just purchased a Primeface Theme&Layout Sentinel. However I've noticed a strange styling on tables in Chrome. The Table header and footer has an orange border. My colleagues don't see this and if I change my chrome profile I don't see it either.

[image: The screenshot is from the Sentinel live preview (Documentation page)]

The original can be seen here: http://www.primefaces.org/sentinel/documentation.xhtml#j_idt38

I've noticed that Chrome is injecting a stylesheet:

```
.ui-widget-header {
    border: 1px solid rgb(231, 143, 8);
    border-image-source: initial;
    border-image-slice: initial;
    border-image-width: initial;
    border-image-outset: initial;
    border-image-repeat: initial;
    background: url(http://primefaces.org/sentinel/images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_35_f6a828_500x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x rgb(246, 168, 40);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Where is this injected stylesheet coming from? How can I stop it? I know that chrome extensions can inject stylesheets but this stylesheet has a url to primefaces, or is that just a red herring and the extension just modified an existing valid stylesheet?

Update:

```
.ui-widget-header {
    /* border: 1px solid #3f7506; */
    /* background: #3a8104 url("images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_33_3a8104_1x100.png") 50% 50% repeat-x; */
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

This is the normal style sheet (it is being overwritten by some other styles, that's why some part is commented out). This style sheet is present in both profiles. As one can see from the URL, the styles normally use relative URIs but the injected one is using an absolute URI.

Comment: You collegues do not have this 'injected' stylesheet? (whatever injection may be, looks like a normal PF stylesheet) And check your zoomlevel...

Comment: No my colleagues don't see this and if I switch my Chrome profile I don't see it either. Zoom level is 100%. When I inspect the component in the other profile I don't have the injected stylesheet. The normal ui-widget-header of the primefaces theme looks completely different (it is there in both cases but is overwritten in the one). Another strange thing is that the url in the injected stylesheet is using an absolute URI while all other styles normally use relative URIs.

Comment: Did you try clearing the cache?

Comment: In my case, renaming the class solved this problem.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Okay I've found the culprit! I've disabled each of my extensions one by one until the page showed correctly. It was the 'CSS Selector Tester'. I think it is a great tool that I often use but it shouldn't screw with my pages when I don't use it!

Interestingly the CSS Selector Tester does not work on the pages where I saw the styling problems. On other pages it works fine.

Comment: ran into the same issue

Comment: Had the same issue with the "Mercury Reader" extension. Removed!

Comment: Ran into the issue because I had an id with the name "adspace" lol and my addBlock was doing that hidding. thx

Comment: Thanks @Ben,
Solved my problem too.  Mine was due to the d3coder extension
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/d3coder/gncnbkghencmkfgeepfaonmegemakcol

Comment: Had the same issue with the "Protection Web Avira" extension. Deactivate!

Comment: Had the same issue. Disabled all my Chrome extensions and the issue went away. Thanks! Now I have to figure out which one it was.

Comment: Also happened with "Dark Reader" extension.

Comment: Mine was "Dark Mode - Dark Reader For Chrome" https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-mode-dark-reader-for/pjbgfifennfhnbkhoidkdchbflppjncb

Answer (score 22):

I had the same issue with injected stylesheet, hiding social buttons from my website.

It turned out my [Adblock](https://adblockplus.org/) plus was blocking Facebook and YouTube social buttons.

Comment: ty you saved me a customer ;)

Comment: Same here. Are there any known solutions for this other than removing adblocker plus?

Comment: @AntoineHolman you can add a website to `Whitelisted websites` it the AdBlock Plus settings

Comment: You can go to ABP:Settings>Advanced>Filter List and disable "`Fanboy's Social Blocking List`" and icons will show up again. I personally think this is overreach, as merely showing icons -from my own website- is not any sort of advert tracking. and complaints to ABP about this need to be made.

Answer (score 7):

Just had this with the 'Save to Pocket' extension overriding rules in a print stylesheet.

Also assuming your Google 'incognito' (privacy mode) browser isn't running your extensions viewing the page 'incognito' can be a quick way to check if a browser extension is the issue.

Comment: Just had the same problem with "Save to Pocket". The extension injected `opacity: 0` to all text inputs and radio buttons, and removed button styles.

Answer (score 7):

If someone stumbles on this as of 24-Feb-2022 because most web pages have black colored background due to `color-scheme: dark` right at the  element by injected stylesheet, the culprit is 'Adobe Acrobat: PDF edit, convert, sign tools' - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adobe-acrobat-pdf-edit-co/efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj

Worked fine after disabling the extension.

Comment: Thank you so much. [Go by Example](https://gobyexample.com/) had a black background with dark text today. I couldn't read it at all. Once II removed the Adobe extension, the page cleared up.

Comment: This needs to be the number 1 comment EVERYWHERE. This took 2 hours to find for me! Adobe, you are no longer my friend!

Answer (score 4):

For Brazilians (especially) who are going through this, check if you have the **Méliuz extension** (chrome://extensions/?id=jdcfmebflppkljibgpdlboifpcaalolg) and disabled it.

Comment: Yup, just happened here

Comment: Same here, I tried disabling other extensions but the Méliuz extension was the one breaking my website.

Answer (score 2):

**How to debug "injected stylesheet" in Chrome**

- Open develop console, goto Network tab
- Filter it something '.css'
- Look for extensions domains that load some CSS files
- Find the extension in your extensions list by filtering domain (like on the pic "hcndlme...")
- Try to disable the extension and reload the page

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to work in Chrome 94.0.4606.81. The Domain column is hidden by default (but still exists, if you right click on the column headers you can show it), but the table doesn't seem to show CSS injected by extensions (although injected scripts are listed). Actually I see it's listed as "fetch" in your screenshot, so maybe it only showed up because of the particular way an extension loaded the CSS.

Comment: You can right-click on any column and select columns which will be visible, just check it on Version 94.0.4606.71 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I know, I said as much. Sorry I couldn't phrase it clearly. (Abutting buts are troublesome.)

Answer (score 1):

In mi case I have disabled the chrome extension called "Nimbus Screenshot & Screen Video Recorder"

Answer (score 0):

remove your newly installed browser extensions and cache, that may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me, the links disappear from the navigation bar because of an extension in chrome called "EPUB READER". I disabled it and the links show up.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be caused by mostly recorder extensions. Mine was caused by "Screen Recorder" chrome extension.

Answer (score 0):

For me the `Shield` feature was causing such a styling problem. Once disabled, the styling was as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was driving me crazy, thanks for posting this.

ExifViewer Pro chrome extension also does this, if anyone else is seeing a randomly appearing tiny little camera icon over certain photos that you can click and pull up EXIF data for the photo. It injects a span in your page like so:

```
<span class="overlayContainer" style="top: 447.375px; left: 124.5px; opacity: 0.5;"></span>
```