# Strange styling through injected stylesheets with class "logo-icon" in Chrome

Tags: html, css, angular, google-chrome, injected-class-name

My project is built on Angular 9+. Everything used to work correctly. But today (07.08.2020) *chrome(Version 84.0.4147.105 (Official Build) (64-bit))* added some injected stylesheet. My **logo-icon** got some styles from chrome. But it works correctly with Mozilla Firefox.

```html
<mat-toolbar>
   ..........
   <div id="nav-brand">
      <a [routerLink]="['']">
        <img class="logo-icon" [src]="logoURL" alr="logo" />
      </a>
    </div>
    .......
</mat-toolbar>
```

[image: My img tag gets styles like this]

Question: Is the "logo-icon" class reserved in chrome? Because, I changed the class name "logo-icon" to "my-logo" and it works correctly again.

Comment: check if you have any extinctions enabled. happens to me once. [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32758890/strange-styling-through-injected-stylesheets-in-chrome)

Comment: Thanks,  it was the "AliExpress Assistant" extension.

Comment: Do you know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Some times chrome save cache and passed this situations, my recommendation is that you work on incognito mode and you save yourself a lot of problems like this or with js

Comment: Thanks, it was the "AliExpress Assistant" extension.

Comment: Do you know why this is happening?